# to adjust the selected row in a datagridview to the middle,as the grid is scrolling down dynamically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to make the current row of the grid which is selected to the middle of the grid view, as the grid is scrolling down dynamically

here I've used code like this;
            If i > 0 Then

```
                dgvDetails.ClearSelection()
                dgvDetails.Rows(i).Selected = True
                dgvDetails.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = i - 1

                dgvDetails.Refresh()
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgvDetails.Rows.Count - 1
  dgvDetails.CurrentCell = dgvDetails(0, i) ' the Cell You need to select 
  dgvDetails.Rows(i).Selected = True
  Application.DoEvents()          
Next
```

Comment: This is not what I want in my code.Anyway thanks for your response.